# Force redirect from https to http .net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, redirect, asp.net-core, .net-core

if there any possible ways to force redirection from https to http? Hosting app on azure, and then somebody share the link in messangers like: www.mywebsite.com and opening it, it redirect to https://www.mywebsite.com. I tried to add rule to webconfig with force redirection, but it applies only then I confirm the dialog with entering non secure website and after the rule with force redirection works. How I can avoid this dialog and the my application was only on http?

Comment: Why don't you want HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

May be `Https Redirection` is enabled in your `Configure` method as follows::

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

     app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // remove this to stop force https redirection


     app.UseMvc(routes =>
     {
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "default",
           template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     });
}
```

Comment: Nope, don't have UseHttpsRedirection and useHists in startup.cs

Comment: Then its related to `azure`. Please check azure hosting settings.

Comment: What exactly I should check? I don't having the forcing ssl applied in settings, even my domain not linked with ssl

Comment: Oh! Really mysterious! On localhost does it direct to https?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Showing that page is normal browser behaviour.

You should get SSL certificate and bind it to your application.